# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus

I have this equation:

$$x=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{c}e^{-\frac{y^2}{x}}dy$$

And I am trying to find $\frac{dx}{dc}$. I tried using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I don't know how to use it in this case since $x$ is inside the integral. Any idea?

Comment: Start with substitution $t = \frac{y}{x}$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule